# Error when deploying PersistenceUnit: IllegalArgumentException expecting collection type [boolean]

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jboss

Since a week I'm getting this error when deploying my ear to JBoss EAP 6.2.0

```
19:48:56,355 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 79) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."Weare-0.1-dev.ear/WeAreEjb.jar#weareUnit": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."Weare-0.1-dev.ear/WeAreEjb.jar#weareUnit": java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expecting collection type [boolean]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:103) [jboss-as-jpa-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122) [jboss-threads-2.1.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.1.Final-redhat-1]
**Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Expecting collection type [boolean]**
    at org.hibernate.ejb.metamodel.AttributeFactory.determineCollectionType(AttributeFactory.java:902)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.metamodel.AttributeFactory$PluralAttributeMetadataImpl.<init>(AttributeFactory.java:756)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.metamodel.AttributeFactory$PluralAttributeMetadataImpl.<init>(AttributeFactory.java:737)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.metamodel.AttributeFactory.determineAttributeMetadata(AttributeFactory.java:520)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.metamodel.AttributeFactory.buildAttribute(AttributeFactory.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.metamodel.MetadataContext.wrapUp(MetadataContext.java:207)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.metamodel.MetamodelImpl.buildMetamodel(MetamodelImpl.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:106)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:914)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:899)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:76)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:200) [jboss-as-jpa-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.access$600(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:57) [jboss-as-jpa-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:99) [jboss-as-jpa-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    ... 4 more
```

I've logged these classes:
**org.hibernate**
**org.jboss.jpa**
**org.jboss.service.msc**

Initially with log level ERROR, then TRACE, ending with ALL, but there is no trace of this error in log files...can anyone tell me which other classes are useful for logging this exception?

I believed that org.hibernate was sufficient, because the exception is thrown by an hibernate class...

Comment: You need to ass the mappings of your entities. That's where the problem might be.

Comment: Hi Vlad, the problem is that I've a very large set of entities (more than 100) with a plenty of @OneToMany relationships inside them...so I want to log where Hibernate expects this collection of type boolean, because examining entity-by-entity is quite impossible it will take too many time.

Comment: Can anyone help me, please? I've this issue on a production environment and I'm going mad